# The problem of the most visited point.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, recursion, percolation

Represent the set $R_{n\times n}=\{1,2,\ldots, n\}\times\{1,2,\ldots, n\} $ as a rectangle of $n$ by $n$ points as in the figures below for example. How to calculate the number of circuits that visit a chosen point in this rectangle? What is the most visited point on this rectangle?

[image]

Making the question more precise we fix the settings below.

- A circuitc $c$ in rectangle $R_{n\times n}$ is defined as a sequence of distinct points $x_{i_1j_1}, x_{i_2j_2},x_{i_2j_2},\ldots, x_{i_{m-1}j_{m-1}}$ and a point $x_{i_{m}j_{m}}=x_{i_{1}j_{1}}$  in $R_{n\times n}$ such that $|i_{k}-i_{k+1}|+|j_{k}-j_{k+1}|=1$ for $k=1,\ldots, m-1$.
- A circuit $c=\{x_{i_1j_1}, x_{i_2j_2},x_{i_2j_2},\ldots, x_{i_{m-1}j_{m-1}},x_{i_{m}j_{m}}\}$ visit a point $x_{ij}$ if $x_{ij}\in c$.
- Let $N_n(x_{ij})$ the total circuits in $R_{n\times n}$ who visit the point $x_{ij}$ .

> **Question.**  How to calculate the value of $N_n(x_{ij})$? If we draw a circuit randomly 
>    which  point $x_{ij}$ has the highest probability to be visited?

Calculations case $n = 1,2,3$ are trivial. I'm trying to calculate the number $N_n(x_{ij})$ by a recursive procedure which reduces the calculation for the case $n$ to $n-1$. But I think the use of this recursion depends on some well-crafted trick that escaped my attempts.

Comment: The following result might be helpful.

**Theorem:** Let $G:=(V,E)$ be a graph and consider its [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) $A_G$. For all $k\in \mathbb N$, the number of paths of lenght $k$ from node $v_i$ to $v_j$is the the entry $i,j$ of the matrix $A^k_G$, for any $i,j\in \{m\in \mathbb N\colon m\leq |V|\}$.

See the proof [here](https://people.math.osu.edu/husen.1/teaching/sp2003/571/graphs.pdf). A couple of  keyterms are *adjacency matrix* and  *number of paths*.

Comment: @GitGud This is the classic solution to the problem of the most visited point. In this case I would have to calculate the number of two distinct paths connecting two points. It seems to be a promising approach. But I have not had progress with this approach.

Comment: I have a suggestion but it might be also hard to calculate. Instead of counting paths on this graph, count the number of coloring the squares in a continuous way. It is obvious that there is an upper bound of $2^{(n-1)(n-1)}$.

Comment: I think the way to approach it might be to relate the probability of each node's appearance in a circuit with its neighbors.  Or maybe look at the probability of each edge appearing in a circuit instead.

Comment: see also another related question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1217371/number-of-circuits-that-surround-the-square).

Answer (score 1):

I think it' strictly linked to the *[self-avoiding path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-avoiding_walk)* (which is slightly different as the circuit doesn't necessary ends where it started); there is also a [detailed study](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Self-AvoidingWalk.html) , and a [partial solution](http://oeis.org/A007764) to what you called $N_n(x_{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor})$, all circuits which visit the origin. Anyway until now, any solution has been found. It can be an idea to consider a circuit that starts from $x_{ab}$ and arrives to $x_{cd}$, and then consider the *reverse paths* (from $x_{cd}$ to $x_{ab}$), remembering not to count the *reverse paths* which intersect the first one, as to create an *[Hamilton path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path)*.

Comment: "Anyway until now, [no?] solution has been found."?

Comment: @Teepeemm No, no solution was found.

Comment: "remembering not to count the _reverse paths_ which intersect the first one": you say that like it was easy!